# Slice a 3D tensor, based on the given sequence length array in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, slice, lstm

I want a tensorflow function, which accepts a 3D matrix and an array ( shape of the array is similar to the first dimension of a 3D matrix ) and I want to slice the elements from each 2D matrix inside the 3D matrix based on the given array. The equivalent numpy looks like as follows. The basic idea is to picking all hidden states of each input in a batch ( avoid the padded ) in a dynamic rnn

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.uniform(-1,1,(3,5,7))
a_length = np.random.randint(5,size=(3))

a_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(a)
a_length_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(a_length)

res = []
for index, length_ in enumerate(a_length):
    res.extend(a[index,:length_,:])
res = np.array(res)
```

Output

```
print(a_length)
array([1, 4, 4])


print(res)

array([[-0.060161  ,  0.36000953,  0.46160677, -0.66576281,  0.28562044,
    -0.60026872,  0.08034777],
   [ 0.04776443,  0.38018207, -0.73352382,  0.61847258, -0.89731857,
     0.57264147, -0.88192537],
   [ 0.92657628,  0.6236141 ,  0.41977008,  0.88720247,  0.44639323,
     0.26165976,  0.2678753 ],
   [-0.78125831,  0.76756136, -0.05716537, -0.64696257,  0.48918477,
     0.15376225, -0.41974593],
   [-0.625326  ,  0.3509537 , -0.7884495 ,  0.11773297,  0.23713942,
     0.30296786,  0.12932378],
   [ 0.88413986, -0.10958306,  0.9745586 ,  0.8975006 ,  0.23023047,
    -0.89991669, -0.60032688],
   [ 0.33462775,  0.62883724, -0.81839566, -0.70312966, -0.00246936,
    -0.95542994, -0.33035891],
   [-0.26355579, -0.58104982, -0.54748412, -0.30236209, -0.74270132,
     0.46329941,  0.34277915],
   [ 0.92837516, -0.06748299,  0.32837354, -0.62863672,  0.86226447,
     0.63604586,  0.0905248 ]])

print(a)
array([[[-0.060161  ,  0.36000953,  0.46160677, -0.66576281,
      0.28562044, -0.60026872,  0.08034777],
    [ 0.26379226,  0.67066755, -0.90139221, -0.86862163,
      0.36405595,  0.71342926, -0.1265208 ],
    [ 0.15007877,  0.82065234,  0.03984378, -0.20038364,
     -0.09945102,  0.71605241, -0.55865999],
    [ 0.27132257, -0.84289149, -0.15493576,  0.74683429,
     -0.71159896,  0.50397217, -0.99025404],
    [ 0.51546368,  0.45460343,  0.87519031,  0.0332339 ,
     -0.53474897, -0.01733648, -0.02886814]],

   [[ 0.04776443,  0.38018207, -0.73352382,  0.61847258,
     -0.89731857,  0.57264147, -0.88192537],
    [ 0.92657628,  0.6236141 ,  0.41977008,  0.88720247,
      0.44639323,  0.26165976,  0.2678753 ],
    [-0.78125831,  0.76756136, -0.05716537, -0.64696257,
      0.48918477,  0.15376225, -0.41974593],
    [-0.625326  ,  0.3509537 , -0.7884495 ,  0.11773297,
      0.23713942,  0.30296786,  0.12932378],
    [ 0.44550219, -0.38828221,  0.35684203,  0.789946  ,
     -0.8763921 ,  0.90155917, -0.75549455]],

   [[ 0.88413986, -0.10958306,  0.9745586 ,  0.8975006 ,
      0.23023047, -0.89991669, -0.60032688],
    [ 0.33462775,  0.62883724, -0.81839566, -0.70312966,
     -0.00246936, -0.95542994, -0.33035891],
    [-0.26355579, -0.58104982, -0.54748412, -0.30236209,
     -0.74270132,  0.46329941,  0.34277915],
    [ 0.92837516, -0.06748299,  0.32837354, -0.62863672,
      0.86226447,  0.63604586,  0.0905248 ],
    [ 0.70272633,  0.17122912, -0.58209965,  0.55557024,
     -0.46295566, -0.33845157, -0.62254313]]])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do that using [`tf.boolean_mask`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/boolean_mask):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

# NumPy/Python implementation
a = np.random.uniform(-1,1,(3,5,7)).astype(np.float32)
a_length = np.random.randint(5,size=(3)).astype(np.int32)
res = []
for index, length_ in enumerate(a_length):
    res.extend(a[index,:length_,:])
res = np.array(res)

# TensorFlow implementation
a_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(a)
a_length_tf = tf.convert_to_tensor(a_length)
# Make a mask for all wanted elements
mask = tf.range(tf.shape(a)[1]) < a_length_tf[:, tf.newaxis]
# Apply mask
res_tf = tf.boolean_mask(a_tf, mask)
# Test
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print(np.allclose(sess.run(res_tf), res))
```

Output:

```
True
```